# How to extract info from xml using bash

Tags: xml, bash

I have this xml, and I need to extract host,port,user,pass. EX:

```
host1 port1 user1 pass1

host2 port2 user2 pass2
```

I tried to do it, but the problem is with getting them in the correct order, thanks for helping.

```
<Server>
            <Host>host1</Host>
            <Port>port1</Port>
            <User>user1</User>
            <Pass>pass1</Pass>
</Server>
<Server>
            <Host>host2</Host>
            <Port>port2</Port>
            <User>user2</User>
            <Pass>pass2</Pass>
</Server>
```

Comment: We are not here to write programs or scripts for you. We are here to help you with the programs or scripts *you have written*. Please show your efforts and reason about the roadblocks you've met.

Comment: Do you think that I am requesting a program?
what kind of programmers you are?

Comment: Yes, you are requesting a program. All you did was throwing a piece of XML and a requirement onto this site, and then wait for someone to solve it for you. That's what I call lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed and paste from GNU Core Utilities:

```
sed -n "/<Server>/,/<\/Server>/{s/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/p}" < filename | paste -d " " - - - -
```

Output:

```
host1 port1 user1 pass1
host2 port2 user2 pass2
```

Comment: thanks for replay, it worked, but I think my question is not complete, so let me append please..
there is some lines between i don't need them
            <Host>host1</Host>
            <blab>bla<blab>
            <Port>port1</Port>
            <User>user1</User>
            <Pass>pass1</Pass>
how do i ignore them, or how do I just take what I need and ignore everything else
thanks

Comment: Insert before `| paste` something like `| grep -v blab` to ignore lines with blab.

Comment: It would be better to use some tools which are optimized for xml parsing like `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` (with Xpath query for example) commands or more powerfull shell languages like perl, python or php (cli).